# Find instance of a formula on a report when it's been hidden

Tags: crystal-reports

It's common practise in Crystal Reports to use a formula on a report that carries out some background logic. But to prevent it displaying, you have to hide the field. Question is, how do you find it again several years later when you've forgotten where it was? I've got a reference to a formula called @AddressedCount but I can't find where it is in the report!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried File->Export->Export Report  (then choose Report Definition from the drop down and hit Export button)  This will produce a text file listing all* the elements in the report which you can load up in your favorite text editor and search for whatever you want.

*There are cases where something in a report is not included in the definition file, but it is rare.

Comment: Thanks for this - the exported report definition allowed me to find which section it was in and then with lots of mouse hovering, find the reference. White on white eh :-)

Comment: you can try changing the background color of the section to something non-white.  sometimes that is easier than the hover method, assuming the formula is actually printing something in white.

Answer (score 2):

In Crystal Reports XI, while in design view you can go to Edit/Find type the field name and click the "Mark All" button. This will highlight the field. Hope that helps.

Comment: Unfortunately still on Crystal Reports 9 here and this doesn't have this functionality. It's a legacy product. We use Microsoft's ReportViewer in new products which is a dream to use compared to CR...

Answer (score 0):

Was facing a similar situation, for the next person to come across this issue, another place to look is in any running total fields that were not used on the report anymore.

That's where my missing formula field was hiding out.

Answer (score 0):

Try refreshing your report. I had a check mark next to the formula showing it was in use after deleting all instances I knew about. I was at wits end trying to find another place the report could have been using the formula but then by happy coincidence I saved the report and the check mark disappeared!